# Grouping data from Database table by months in datatable

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, datatables

I currently have a datatable which contains information of jobs I have done.

```
 ID  |    date    |  income  |  payment  |  profit
==================================================
  1  | 2019/01/01 |   100    |    75     |   25
  2  | 2019/01/03 |   200    |    150    |   50
  3  | 2019/02/02 |   350    |    200    |   150
  4  | 2019/04/05 |   100    |    75     |   25
  5  | 2019/05/03 |   500    |    300    |   200
  6  | 2019/07/07 |   200    |    160    |   40
```

I am looking to turn this data into a bargraph using highcharts.js but first I need to group everything by month in the form of the table below

```
Month   |  Income  |  Payment  |  Profit
========================================
January |   300    |   225     |  75
February|   350    |   200     |  50
March   |    0     |    0      |  0
April   |   100    |   75      |  25
May     |   700    |   460     |  240
```

I am unsure how to find the values based on the dates.

I was looking to have something like this:

```
select date ,income, payment, From table1
    SUM( CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m/%Y') = 01/2019 THEN `income`) as jan_income
    SUM( CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m/%Y') = 01/2019 THEN `payment`) as jan_payment
    SUM( CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m/%Y') = 01/2019 THEN `profit`) as jan_profit
```

and populate `table2` the table using

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo "<tr>
            <td>January</td>
            <td>".$result['jan_income']."</td>
            <td>".$result['jan_payment']."</td>
            <td>".$result['jan_profit']."</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>February</td>
            <td>".$result['feb_income']."</td>
            <td>".$result['feb_payment']."</td>
            <td>".$result['feb_profit']."</td>
          </tr>
```

If anyone could advise on the correct way to achieve this I would be very grateful.

UPDATE... NEW PHP based on NBK's answer

```
<tbody>
    <?php
     //Connect to database (same connection details as all tables so know this works)
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $sql = "SELECT date, income, payment FROM add_job
            DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%M %Y') AS MontnameYear, 
            MIN(DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%M')) AS MonthName, 
            SUM(`income`) AS income,
            SUM(`payment`) AS payment,
            MIN(`date`) AS mdate
            GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%M %Y')
            ORDER by mdate;";

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            echo "<tr>
                      <td>".$result['MonthName']."</td>
                      <td>".$result['income']."</td>
                      <td>".$result['payment']."</td>
                      <td>".$result['profit']."</td>
                  </tr>";
            }
        } 
        else { 
            echo "0 results";
        }
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier, when You use this sql state,emt

```
Select
  DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%M %Y') MontnameYear,MIN(DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%M')) MonthName
  , SUM(`income`) income,SUM(`payment`) payment, SUM(`profit`) profit
  ,MIN(`date`) mdate
FROM table1
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%M %Y')
ORDER by mdate;
```

Explanation:

> MonthnameYear is need to group the select ti get the right income...
>
> MonthName is to show the correct Monthname in your table, because
>   you wanted it so  would have taken January 2019
>
> SUM(..) is clear it gets you the sum of the Column grouped by Month and
>   year
>
> mdate I had to sort it correctly, so i had to use the actual date to
>   sort

[DBfiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5fbeb3a791b187dc87eec11c4d364478)

Which gives you this result

```
MontnameYear    MonthName   income  payment     profit  mdate
January 2019    January     300     225         75      2019-01-01 01:00:00
February 2019   February    350     200         150     2019-02-02 01:00:00
April 2019      April       100     75          25      2019-04-05 02:00:00
May 2019        May         500     300         200     2019-05-03 02:00:00
July 2019       July        200     160         40      2019-07-07 02:00:00
```

And then make this in your php code, you have only onetable row, which is looped through, and it produces the same3 result.

```
while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  echo "<tr>
          <td>".$result['MonthName']."</td>
          <td>".$result['income']."</td>
          <td>".$result['payment']."</td>
          <td>".$result['profit']."</td>
        </tr>"
 }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. I cant get the query to run when using PHP to populate a datatable. it is telling me `No data available in table`... are there any slight changes that usually need to be made when going from a query like this to one that can be used in PHP to populate a datatable? as I dont usderstand why it works perfectly here but not on my own site

Comment: Please post from your php file at least everything around the sql  area. , so that i can check it. Have you programmed a erro handling in your code, so that eventually we could get a better  idea if there is something wring

Comment: After adding to my question, I noticed a slight change to make and it has worked. thank you :-)